# Clear Intents between instrumentation tests

Tags: android, android-intent, android-espresso

One of my Espresso tests is apparently failing because a broadcast intent triggered by the previous test is arriving part way through the subsequent test.  At this point, the application is in an inconsistent state and missing some `SharedPreferences` which are expected by the intent handler.

Is there a way to make sure that all waiting intents have been processed or cancelled before starting an Espresso test?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to clear intents that are already dispatched. However you can get around this by tweaking your "previous test".

If you want to fully take advantage of Espresso you have to reduce the scope of your test as small as possible. So instead of broadcasting an intent and verifying what happens next, try stubbing your intents.

Use `IntentsTestRule` instead of `ActivityTestRule` and stub out all internal intents (sometimes even the external ones) using the below code:

```
intending(isInternal()).respondWith(new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null));
```

Now in your "previous test", check if the right intent is getting broadcasted using something like:

`intended(hasComponent("com.example.something.SomeActivity"));`

This way, you can test your functionality without actually broadcasting any intents. I always stub my Internal and External intents and verify if the right intent is getting triggered in all my tests. This way the next activity doesn't get launched and my Espresso tests are faster and stable. Always ensure to test only what you are want to test, and keep the scope really small.

Read more: https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/

Comment: Thanks, great answer and looks like it will be really useful if I want to test intents more specifically.  In my case though, intents are being fired in click handlers of UI elements.  I'm not trying to test the intents themselves, but they in turn trigger UI updates.  I'll have a think if the code can be better isolated.

Comment: Even in this case, I would suggest you stub the intents. If the 'broadcasted intent' is a side effect of `click handlers` then it's safe to stub the intents and still verify your UI updates. If your `broadcasted intent` is the one causing the UI updates, you need to split your test into two. First test case: test if clicking on the `click handler` fires the required intent. Second test case: launch your activity with the `broadcasted intent` and check for the UI updates.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem testing two intents,
one to share text and another to share audio.
I managed to do it by calling between the intents.

```
Intents.init()
//
Intents.release()
```

I don't know if it is the right way but is working on the question.

Let say I have to check two Intents with action CHOOSER.
Even my intents are ACTION_SEND, I have a CHOOSER in my code to send intent.

```
    Intents.init()
    testIntent1
    Intents.release()

    Intents.init()
    testIntent2
    Intents.release()
```

```
testIntent1() {
    Matcher<Intent> expectedIntent = getIntentMatcherChooser();
    String textInET = "share this text";

    replaceTextCloseKeyboard(R.id.et_main, text);
    openDrawerClickItem(R.id.nav_item_share_text);

    intended(expectedIntent);
}   

getIntentMatcherChooser(){
    Matcher<Intent> expectedIntent = allOf(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER));
    intending(expectedIntent).respondWith(new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(0, null));
}
```